# How to attach 3D object to screen?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

How can I make a 3D object to be attached to my phone, so I can move around, and then after I click on the screen - the 3D object should remain in the current position in 3D space?

Comment: Would it be enough to parent to and offset your object from the camera (or write a script to offset it on Update) and un-parent (or stop updating) when you get a touch input?

Comment: @MrDos Yes, so we have 2 objects "content" and empty "container". "Content" is aprented to the camera. When I click a button "Container" jumps to the current position of the "Content", and "Content" unparenting from the camera and parenting to the "Container". Then I want to be able to parent it tocameera again to move to another place.

Comment: Simple way of adapting what you already have would be to keep an object under your camera and just toggle the parenting of `Content` between `Container` and the new object under your camera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Native RealityKit approach***

@Rumata, here's how your code might look like for `stick-and-drop` methodology. A sphere object will be automatically dropped in 5 seconds after app's launch. The same way you can implement Tap Gesture (via Storyboard or programmatically, it's up to you).

```swift
import ARKit
import RealityKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let mesh = MeshResource.generateSphere(radius: 0.1)
        let sphere = ModelEntity(mesh: mesh)
        sphere.transform.translation = [0, 0,-1]

        let anchor = AnchorEntity(.camera)
        sphere.setParent(anchor)
        arView.scene.addAnchor(anchor)
                
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.0) {
            
            let frame = self.arView.session.currentFrame
            let envAnchor = AnchorEntity(world: (frame?.camera.transform)!)
            
            sphere.removeFromParent()
            envAnchor.addChild(sphere)

            self.arView.scene.addAnchor(envAnchor)
        }
    }
}
```